# how to select union of two columns of same table in hql

Tags: mysql, select, hql, distinct, union

I need to retrieve all the account numbers of the transaction table/object which given below. Using mysql for database.

Entity Class

```
 public class Transaction implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "cr_account_ref")
    private String crAccountRef;

    @Column(name = "dr_account_ref")
    private String drAccountRef;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private String amount;

// getters and setters.

}
```

My Table

```
| cr_account_ref      |  dr_account_ref      |  amount    |
|----------------------------------------------------------
|1000001              |2000009               |  100       |
|1000002              |2000008               |  500       |
|1000001              |2000006               |  100       |
|1000003              |2000004               |  500       |
|1000005              |2000008               |  611       |
|1000001              |2000009               |  300       |
|1000002              |2000004               |  120       |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

What i need is, distinct of all the account numbers(both debit and credit.).

```
| cr_account_ref      |
|----------------------
|1000001              |
|1000002              |
|1000003              |
|1000005              |
|2000004              |
|2000006              |
|2000008              |
|2000009              |
-----------------------
```

This is easy with pure jdbc, but i need to do the this with HQL.